# Flutter hot reload not working in android studio

Tags: flutter

When I comment on New Text ('41 ') and then I press HOT RELOAD but it doesn't change, I've pressed a lot it hasn't changed, then I press the RUN button then it works fine

Anyone got the same problem?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cagm5.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are using a stateless or stateful widget, the hot reload/refresh only works when you are dealing with state.

If you just run your main class without any state Widget, you'll have to run the application each time that you want to test a new modification.